# FOR /F issue running from a text file + counting up value

Tags: batch-file

Here is something I'm struggeling with:

```
Title Scanning online computers: && set /a title_count=0
call :next


:next
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%a IN (workstation.txt) do (
title Scanning for online computers: %title_count% / %workstation%
ping -n 1 %%a | find "bytes=" >nul
set /a title_count=title_count+=1

if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
set color=%%a && call includes\what.bat %color_pass% && echo %%a >> logs\reachable.txt
) else ( 
set color=%%a && call includes\what.bat %color_fail% && echo %%a >> logs\unreachable.txt && echo %%a, offline, %     date%, %time% >> logs\offline.txt
)
)
```

The problem I have here is that the function TITLE is not getting updated while the variable %count_title% is counting up through the script.

```
set /a title_count+=1
```

doesn't work either

It's displayed as:

```
 Scanning for online computers 0 / 5
```

Can sombody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Illusion

Hi,

I've tried it the way as suggested:
It finishes the rest of the script when using the last GOTO :EOF
IT doesn't make sense to me, if I remove the last GOTO :eof, only the first row in workstation.txt is getting processed/parsed.

```
       Scanning online computers: && set /a title_count+=1`
       call :next
       ::added as possibly missing
       GOTO :EOF

       :next
        FOR /F "tokens=1" %%a IN (workstation.txt) DO CALL :pingstation %%a
        GOTO :EOF

        :pingstation
        title Scanning for online computers: %title_count% / %workstation%
        ping -n 1 %1 | find "bytes=" >nul
        set /a title_count+=1

        if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        set color=%1 && call includes\what.bat %color_pass% && echo %1 >> logs\reachable.txt
        ) else ( 
         set color=%1 && call includes\what.bat %color_fail% && echo %1 >> logs\unreachable.txt && echo %1, offline, %date%, %time% >> logs\offline.txt
        )

        goto :eof

        )
```

Answer (score 3):

Read this: [Environment variable expansion occurs when the command is read](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx).

Salient points:

- Your variables are expanded right when `for` command (and its entire body enclosed in parentheses) is parsed.
- Use `!VARNAME!` instead of `%VARNAME%` to avoid it.
- For better portability across OS versions/setups, it's a good idea to stick a  `setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning of your batch file.

Also, make sure there is a goto (e.g., `goto :EOF`) after `call :next`, because the code as posted will run through `next` one extra time.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and changing the `%` syntax to the `!` one when addressing vars inside the loop that are initialised within that very loop, just as *atzz* has suggested.

But there's a different approach. You can simply move the body of the loop to a(nother) subroutine. That way the variables would expand as expected.

```
Title Scanning online computers: && set /a title_count=0
call :next
::added as possibly missing
GOTO :EOF

:next
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%a IN (workstation.txt) DO CALL :pingstation %%a
GOTO :EOF

:pingstation
title Scanning for online computers: %title_count% / %workstation%
ping -n 1 %1 | find "bytes=" >nul
set /a title_count+=1

if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
set color=%1 && call includes\what.bat %color_pass% && echo %1 >> logs\reachable.txt
) else ( 
set color=%1 && call includes\what.bat %color_fail% && echo %1 >> logs\unreachable.txt && echo %1, offline, %date%, %time% >> logs\offline.txt
)
```